# Best way to show combat encounters on physical map

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm new to dming and dnd overall. So for starters, I tried playing a combat encounter on an elctronic map but that didnt go as planned and ruined first play. I want to know how I can present these encounters on a physical grid.

Comment: can you give some more detail: what sorts of things went wrong, what you're trying to achieve with your combat representation, &c. Since you're new you may not have a lot of specifics in mind, yet--feel free to just describe the session you're running in your daydreams and people here will surely try to help you get there.

Comment: Is this question a *really* basic “how does one use a battle-mat for combat?” kind of question? (If it's not, what practical difficulty are you having with using a physical grid?) We do answer even very basic questions, but we need to be clear on the problem being a lack of fundamental understanding so that answers can focus on the correct difficulty being experienced.

Comment: How were you using the digital map? Via chromecast to a TV in a top down or angled 3D view, or a projector on the wall? Were you moving your players pieces, or did they have some agency? What method were you using to establish fog of the unknown?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Maybe you want to look at a YouTube video, for example the critical role show campaign 2, in many fights they use physical maps. Maybe it helps you get a better ideo of what you are asking. Often someone posts a little overview in the comments.